# How do I load CSV file into Amazon Redshift from OS Windows using Python?

Tags: python, csv, amazon-web-services, upload, amazon-redshift

I need to load CSV files from my desktop (Windows) to Redshift tables.

Can someone demonstrate implementing this process in Python?

I am assuming that the script will accept the CSV file name and connection details.

The result of execution of the script is CSV data appended to Redshift table.

Comment: You can start by checking the online documentation and try a few libraries https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html  post some code and any problems you are encountering so we can help you

Answer (score 1):

Start by uploading the file to S3 as the most effective way to load data to Redshift is by COPY from S3.

You can use the AWS SDK for S3: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.put

The next step is to run a COPY command. This is done through an SQL connection. Here you have a few options, some are using the standard JDBC/ODBC connection to Redshift/PostgreSQL (pyodbc - https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc, for example), or a dedicated library for such COPY (http://initd.org/psycopg/, for example). This COPY command will point to the S3 object that you uploaded in step 1.